# Have any non-Vulcans adopted the Vulcan logic-based belief system?

Tags: star-trek

In the shows, movies, and official books have any non-Vulcans ever adopted the Vulcan system of belief (logic-based religion/philosophy, eliminating/ignoring emotions) and practices?  Lets not count Spock (who is half human of course).

Comment: If not, it would be a fascinating thing to explore in the new series

Comment: Sarek's two human wives might be candidates, depending on how far they adapted to Vulcan culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two examples that come to mind:

In season 3 episode 5 of the original series, called "Is there no truth in Beauty?" Dr. Miranda Jones, a human telepath (who was apparently born with the ability) acts as a telepathic ambassador to a race of energy based creatures called the Medusans. This human has studied on Vulcan for several years and was able to learn Vulcan telepathic techniques. She also appears to suppress her emotions more so than humans otherwise would -- although she doesn't do so completely.

Additionally, in season 3 episode 14 of Voyager, called "Alter Ego," Harry Kim falls in love with what appears to be a holodeck character and then asks Tuvok, a Vulcan aboard the ship, to teach him how to suppress emotions as Vulcans do. Later in the episode, he quits doing this, but it still is an example of a non-Vulcan adopting parts of the Vulcan philosophy.